# Custom Analyzer in Lucene 8.5

Tags: java, lucene, wordnet, keyword-expansion

I am trying to implement a `CustomAnalyzer` using Lucene 8.5. It's purpose it to expand queries with synonyms from wordnet. My code is the following:

```
private static CustomAnalyzer customAnalyzer() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> sargs = new HashMap<>();
        sargs.put("synonyms", "wn_s.pl");
        sargs.put("format", "wordnet");

        CustomAnalyzer.Builder builder = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                .withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
                .addTokenFilter(EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory.class)
                .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
                .addTokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.class)
                .addTokenFilter(PorterStemFilterFactory.class)
                .addTokenFilter(SynonymGraphFilterFactory.class, sargs);
        return builder.build();
}
```

However, when I run it I get this exception

```
java.io.IOException: Resource not found: wn_s.pl
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ClasspathResourceLoader.openResource(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:77)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymGraphFilterFactory.loadSynonyms(SynonymGraphFilterFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymGraphFilterFactory.inform(SynonymGraphFilterFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer$Builder.applyResourceLoader(CustomAnalyzer.java:544)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer$Builder.addTokenFilter(CustomAnalyzer.java:321)
    at Main.customAnalyzer(Main.java:78)
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

The file exists, it's permissions are correct, and the specified exception occurs even if I use an absolute path.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, `ClasspathResourceLoader` indicates the resource should be on the classpath. Did you put it there? If so, how?

Comment: That was it. I've put it in the `src/main/resources` and it now works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `wn_s.pl` was not in the ClassPath. I moved the file to the `src/main/resources` directory and the issue was fixed.

Thanks @Thomas for the suggestion.